# Disable clipping of "Selection Handles/Callipers" in UITextView

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, xib

I'm having a hard time googling this one because I'm not sure what to call it but here's a screenshot.

[image: ClippedBug]

If you look carefully you'll notice the right selection handle is being clipped, making it near impossible to touch (if you really focus you can grab it).

I've disabled "Clip subviews" on the red `UITextView` and it still clips it

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem.m. Can you share additional details about environment? UITextView setup?

Comment: @Keenle I'm packaging up the xib file forya.

Comment: @Keenle try this http://www.speedyshare.com/UbqzK/badCell.zip You'll have to just setup the main.storyboard as your main interface

Answer (score 3):

In the implementation of `FMProblemTableViewCell`, you need to disable `clipsToBounds` for `_messageContent`. That's the view that is clipping when I try your sample code.

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
  self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"outgoingStringMessage" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
  _messageContent.text = string;

  //corners
  _messageBubbleView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
  _messageContent.clipsToBounds = NO; // <--- this is what fixed it
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by explicitly setting `clipsToBounds` to `false` **programatically**. If you disable it via Storyboard and inspect the view, you'll see it's not actually disabled. This is very odd behaviour, maybe it's a bug on Apple's side?

```
self.textView.clipsToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some top & bottom inset to your text view's text container.

```
textView.textContainerInset.top += 4
textView.textContainerInset.bottom += 4
```